# Stemming without free-text search in stardog

Tags: stardog

I am using stardog as semantic database.

Query: except all **kinds** of **Mango** & **vegetable**.

Expected output: except all **kind** of **Mangoes** & **vegetables**.

Actual output: 0 results.

I have tried English Analyzer library for stemming. But as per my understanding, it works only when we search with free-text (i.e. tag:stardog:api:property:textMatch).

If I enable free-text, I don't mind results like 'except all **kinds** of **vegetable**'. But as free-text matches all words and combinations, many results are irrelevent (eg. except trips).

Current query:

```
  select * where {
  ?s a p:NamedEntity .

  ?s hasTitle ?l.

  (?l ?score) <tag:stardog:api:property:textMatch>
      'except all **kinds** of **Mango** & **vegetable**'
  }order by desc(?score)
```

My Question:

1. Can English analyzer be used without free-text search?
2. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can [specify custom analyzers](https://github.com/stardog-union/stardog-examples/tree/develop/examples/analyzer).